# Change FDR % to adjust p.values

Tags: r

I am using  `p.adjust` to compute FDR adjustment:

```
p.adjust(p=data,method="fdr")
```

How do I calculate FDR of 15%?

Comment: I assume `data` is a vector of p-values, then maybe you can do something like `p.adjust(p=data,method="fdr") < 0.15`?

Comment: Have you read the [publication](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf) on which this method is based?